# Pass Data from One PHP Page to Another using header()

Tags: php, header, location

I want to send data from one PHP file to another PHP file in a subfolder where the first PHP file is present.  I have a folder named `folder1` which has contains a PHP file named `file1.php` and I want to call another file named `file2.php` in a subfolder of `folder1` named `folder2`.  I am using the `header()` function like this in `file1.php`:

```
$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$uri   = rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']), '/\\');
$extra = 'folder1/folder2/file2.php';
header("location:http://$host$uri/$extra?sms=".$msg."&num=".$msg_num);
```

Data is not passing.  Is there any solution using `header()`?  I can't use `cURL` because of some restrictions.

Comment: Can you be more specific with what "data is not passing" means?

Comment: query string parameters are empty in file2.php. Even though they are being filled with valid data in file1.php

Comment: What do you get when you `echo "location:http://$host$uri/$extra?sms=".$msg."&num=".$msg_num;`

Comment: @jprofitt i am getting the data when i echo like that... but data does not get passed to file2

Comment: I don't see you initializing `$msg` and `$msg_num`. As @jprofitt said, basically debugging 101, print the result and see if it matches your expectations. The only possibility here is that those variables aren't set and the query string is loaded with empty variables. Or, but you didn't say so, you've already echo'd something and you get the warning that headers are already sent, and the redirect never takes place. How do you see that the "data does not get passed to file2"? Have you tried `var_dump($_SERVER);`?

Comment: @codecaster I have initialized and assigned it. I can say the data is not getting to file2.php as there is no data in the query string as i can see the browser

Comment: @nickb i cannot use sessions for my file :(

Comment: Do you actually get redirected to this file2.php? And what **do** you see in the address bar?

Answer (score 4):

The following code works:

`file1.php`:

```
<?php

header( 'Location: inner/file2.php?x=1&y=2&z=3' );

?>
```

`inner/file2.php`:

```
<?php

print '<pre>';

var_dump( $_GET );

print '</pre>';

?>
```

The result of visiting `http://localhost/testing/file1.php` is a redirect to `http://localhost/testing/inner/file2.php?x=1&y=2&z=3` which displays:

```
array(3) {
  ["x"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["y"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["z"]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

I would suggest copying over these test files and proving to yourself that the basic concept of redirecting with passed values is working.  Then, build up the rest of your code around a known-good kernel.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Without an example of the variables you want to send, it's kind of hard to tell what the problem might be, but a possible problem could be the characters in the variables.

To make sure there are no invalid characters, you can use `urlencode()`, perhaps in combination with `htmlentities()`, see the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php):

```
header("location:http://$host$uri/$extra?sms=".urlencode($msg)."&num=".urlencode($msg_num));
```

Comment: Also, you need to make sure that `file2.php` is in fact looking for the correct parameters.

Comment: i want to pass sms and num to file2.php from file1.php... i am assigning them correctly and taking the correct parameters using $_get in file2.php... but there is no data in the query string itself